# How to update an entry which has many to many relationship in EF?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a model as follows:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

And the category model is as follows:

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

I want to update an entry for a product. Which is working but if I edit a product with no categories I get an error. How can I add new product with or without categories?

And how can I update an existing product with multiple categories to no category?

Can someone explain what the approach for this is?

Comment: make categories in Product entity virtual.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this.

Here's a product to update.

```
//get your product
var product = context.Products.Include("Categories")
        .First();

// remove categories for product
product.Categories.Clear();
//save changes
context.SaveChanges();

/* if that doesn't work try this alternate way to remove categories for product*/
var categories = product.Categories.ToList();
foreach (var c in categories)
product.Categories.Remove(c);

context.SaveChanges();


// To add a new product:
var product = new Product() { Name = "Cool product", Code = "4&meridians", price = 5.0 };

context.Products.Add(product);
context.SaveChanges();
```

To add categories to a new product do this before the SaveChanges call:

```
product.Categories.Add(new Category(){ Name = "cool category", Code = "rf7)425" });
```